# Button that jumps to top at bottom center

Tags: html, css, image, button, centering

I'm creating little html offline pages to display on touchscreens as text panels in kiosk mode (tiny museum with no internet). My background image is the actual scrolling text panel and I've figured that part out.

I would like a button at the center bottom of the page that "jumps" to the top of the page when a visitor touches it. I'm trying to get the button to position at the bottom center of the page but I'm brand new to this and can't figure out what code works.

I'll try to upload some images of what is going on, what I want, and my code.

I'll try to provide the images if I can...

[image: where it is stuck]

[image: what I want]

[image: code]

Comment: Hi @EmilyJ, can you provide more info and paste the code here instead of posting a photo of the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the button be "glued" to TOP of view as more intuitive on the GoTo edge. You can use bottom of screen by replace where I have set Top 0

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />
<!-- set screen 3000px big to show it functions, and buttons don't play well with center so set the button left offset (will need adjust for a given screen width and font size -->

<style>
a:-webkit-any-link { color: black ; text-decoration: none; font-size: 20px;}
body { height: 3000px ; background-color: #2a3a1f ; color: #fef1f0; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: center;}
button { Left: 300px ; position: fixed; top: 0 ; text-decoration: none; }
</style></head><body>

<button type="button"><a href="#top">Please scroll down for more details, and touch here to return to "Top of Page"</a></button>
<br><h1>Hello Browser, Welcome to the Small Museum</h1>

<div>
Here be many interesting Art & Facts to explore, especially below. 
</div>

</body></html>
```